# send console error message if I forget to import a element

Tags: polymer

When putting together lots of elements I tend to forget imports. It takes me a long time to find out why my app is not working and when I suspect I forgot a import, to find in which element I forgot it.

Can polymer trow a console error message if it encounters a <*-*> element that has no polymer definition or uses a attribute that is not available?

example if I forget

```
<link rel="import" href="components/core-animated-pages/transitions/slide-from-right.html">
```

or just a custom element

```
<link rel="import" href="new-element.html">
```

Chrome will not complain at any point in the app running.

And if that would be possible could the other way around also be possible to scan for imports that are not needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with building this sort of error checking directly into Polymer:

1. It's not actually an error to create a `<foo-element squid="tentacles"></foo-element>` that has no custom element definition. There are legitimate use cases for such things.
2. Testing for some of these problems can negatively impact performance.

However, it's clear that there is a large class of problems where some simple static analysis or run-time checking could save developers a lot of time.

The plan of record is to construct a dev-tool extension, at least on Chrome at first, that can take the time to do these analyses, and report a series of warning conditions, statistics, and other debugging info.

Stay tuned to the Polymer website for more information.

Comment: Now that you mention a dev-tool extension, my mind can not even grasp the possibilities you can achieve with it for debugging, thanks! :)

Comment: Can you make a github repository for this plugin please, even if it just contains a Readme list of current planned features so we can submit more debug feature request?